# Splitting rotated paragraph with iText

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText library in Java (version 5.5.9). I am trying to render a rotated text split into two different rectangles on a page.

First, consider a simplier task. Just render a paragraph rotated 90 degrees clockwise. I am able to do this with the following code:

```
final Document document = new Document(PageSize.A3);
document.setMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
final PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
document.open();

final String text = "some very long text ...";
final float textWidth = 600f;
final float textHeight = 100f;

final Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(text, myFont);
paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
paragraph.setLeading(0f, 1.2f);

final PdfTemplate textTemplate = PdfTemplate.createTemplate(pdfWriter, textWidth, textHeight);

final ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(textTemplate);
columnText.setSimpleColumn(0, 0, textWidth, textHeight);
columnText.addElement(paragraph);
columnText.go();

final Image textImage = Image.getInstance(textTemplate);
textImage.setInterpolation(true);
textImage.scaleAbsolute(textWidth, textHeight);
textImage.setRotationDegrees(-90f);
textImage.setAbsolutePosition(0f, 800f);

document.add(textImage);

document.close();
```

However, the text is too long to fit in that rectangle.
I would like to define one more rectangle on the page and render the rest of the text in this second rectangle.
The text should be rotated 90 degrees clockwise in both rectangles.
The text should be split automatically (just like a long paragraph continues automatically on the next page).

Is this possible with iText? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution of my own question:

I define two instances of `PdfTemplate` but I stay only with a single instance of `ColumnText`. The `PdfTemplate` associated with the `ColumnText` is switched and the method `go()` is called once for each template.

The appropriate part of the code from my question should be modified in the following way:

```
final PdfTemplate textTemplate1 = PdfTemplate.createTemplate(pdfWriter, textWidth, textHeight);
final PdfTemplate textTemplate2 = PdfTemplate.createTemplate(pdfWriter, textWidth, textHeight);

final ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(textTemplate1);
columnText.setSimpleColumn(0f, 0f, textTemplate1.getWidth(), textTemplate1.getHeight());
columnText.addElement(paragraph);
columnText.go();

columnText.setCanvas(textTemplate2);
columnText.setSimpleColumn(0f, 0f, textTemplate2.getWidth(), textTemplate2.getHeight());
columnText.go();
```

The method `go()` returns an `int` status. I can test this status if I am not sure whether there is some more text that did not fit in the last template.

```
final int goResult = columnText.go();
if (ColumnText.hasMoreText(goResult)) {
    ...
}
```

Note that my solution is based on this example:

https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-continue-field-output-second-page